# How to INSERT into a table whose name is stored as variable inside the same script?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

To brief the question, I have a table named `partitions_info` which maintains the details of all other tables I am using.

Columns of `partitions_info` are `tablename`, `starttime`, `endtime`

I have compiled following trigger for selecting a particular table name from `partitions_info` table (schema shown above) based on some conditions.
I store the table name into a variable `table_name`. Now how can I insert some values into the table which is stored in variable `table_name`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_fun()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    table_name varchar(65);
BEGIN
    SELECT tablename FROM partitions_info INTO table_name WHERE starttime<'2015-12-04 14:23:56' AND endtime>'2015-12-04 14:23:56';
    IF table_name IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO default_table VALUES (NEW.*);
    END IF;
    # Here I wanted to insert into table name which is stored in variable whose name is stored in "table_name" variable declared above
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the dynamic `INSERT` can look like this (including some other minor improvements):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_fun()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
   table_name text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO table_name p.tablename 
   FROM   partitions_info p
   WHERE  p.starttime < '2015-12-04 14:23:56'
   AND    p.endtime   > '2015-12-04 14:23:56';

   IF FOUND THEN  -- simpler, cheaper, safer
     EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' VALUES ($1.*)'
     USING NEW;
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO default_table VALUES (NEW.*);
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [PL/pgSQL: General Way to Update N Columns in Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148585/pl-pgsql-general-way-to-update-n-columns-in-trigger/25154599#25154599)
- [Self-managing PostgreSQL partition tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891320/self-managing-postgresql-partition-tables)