# How to pass NEW.* to EXECUTE in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a simple mission is inserting huge MD5 values into tables (partitioned table), and have created a trigger and also a trigger function to instead of `INSERT` operation. And in function I checked the first two characters of `NEW.md5` to determine which table should be inserted.

```
DECLARE
  tb text;
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    tb = 'samples_' || left(NEW.md5, 2);
    EXECUTE(format('INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);', tb, NEW.*)); <- WRONG
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
```

The question is how to concat the `NEW.*` into the SQL statement?

Comment: Please *always* include your version of Postgres. And I very much prefer to see complete function definitions including header and footer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best with the [`USING` clause of `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION foo ()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
     EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT $1.*'
                  , 'samples_' || left(NEW.md5, 2);
     USING NEW;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$func$;
```

`EXECUTE` does not require parentheses.
And you are aware that identifiers are folded to lower case unless quoted where necessary: format specifier `%I` instead of `%s` for [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) - which also defends against SQL injection attempts.

More details:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function?lq=1)
- [How to dynamically use TG_TABLE_NAME in PostgreSQL 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519044/how-to-dynamically-use-tg-table-name-in-postgresql-8-2/7617533#7617533)

Comment: In a trigger function, I was not able to use `NEW` when passed in `FORMAT(.., NEW)`. When I passed it with `EXECUTE 'Query' USING NEW;` I was able to use it `$1.colname`. I thought `FORMAT` parameters are identical to `USING` parameters, but it is not the case..

Comment: @RTD: `EXECUTE` and `format()` are completely different beasts. The former executes dynamic SQL in a separate execution context and you can pass *values* in a `USING` clause (as arbitrary data types) - not SQL keywords or identifiers. Just like with prepared statements. The latter is a plain function concatenating strings (type `text`). You can only pass `text` - or data types with a registered implicit cast to `text`.