# Replace double quotes with single quotes in Postgres (plpgsql)

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am building a trigger function in plpgsql for my partitioned table and I've got all of my logic working, but am having trouble inserting the actual record into my table.

I have to reference my specific table by a variable reference, so that (as far as I understand) forces me to use an `EXECUTE` command, as so:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' VALUES ' || NEW.*;
```

However, this does not handle unpacking the record stored in `NEW` in a way that Postgres' `INSERT` function can understand. It converts the record into a string while preserving all of the double quotes within. I.e. the above turns into the following upon execution:

```
INSERT INTO cfs_hgt_05152016_05202016
VALUES ("2016-05-16 00:00:00","2016-05-12 06:00:00",HGT,"1000 mb",9,-71,-38.5371)
```

The problem with this is Postgres thinks these values are now columns due to the double quotes.

> ```
> COPY cfs_hgt_master, line 1: ""2016-05-16 00:00:00","2016-05-12 06:00:00","HGT","1000 mb",9,-71,-38.5371"
> ERROR:  column "2016-05-16 00:00:00" does not exist
> ```

I tried to remedy this by the following:

```
record_text := regexp_replace(NEW.*, '"', '\'', 'gi');
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' VALUES ' || record_text;
```

But escaping the single quote like that produces an error:

> ```
> psql:cfs_hgt_trigger_function.sql:36: ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "' || record_text;
> LINE 30: ...  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' VALUES ' || recor...
>                                                               ^
> ```

Could someone help me figure out how to either properly escape that single quote, or suggest an alternative means of accomplishing my task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't convert *values* to their text representation *at all*. Pass values with the [**`USING`** clause of `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

And escape table names properly. You can use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for this:

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT $1.*', tablename)
USING NEW;
```

Details:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function?lq=1)
- [How to pass NEW.* to EXECUTE in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408171/how-to-pass-new-to-execute-in-trigger-function/36415706#36415706)