# How to pass schema name dynamically in a function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-11

I have function called `list_customers`, taking `i_entity_id, i_finyear` as input params. The schema name is built from `i_finyear`, I need to execute the query based on the given schema.

I tried the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_customers(i_entity_id integer,
i_finyear integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(entity_id integer, client_id
integer, financial_yr integer) LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS 
$BODY$
declare finyear integer := i_finyear; 
    schema_1 text := 'tds'||''||i_finyear;
begin 
    set search_path to schema_1;
return query select
d.entity_id, d.client_id, d.financial_yr
from schema_1.deductor d where d.entity_id = 1331;
end; 
$BODY$;
```

Then:

```
select tds2020.list_customers(1331,2022);
```

[imagelink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upPY4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_customers(i_entity_id int, i_finyear int)
  RETURNS TABLE (entity_id int, client_id int, financial_yr int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
     'SELECT d.entity_id, d.client_id, d.financial_yr
      FROM   tds' || i_finyear || '.deductor d
      WHERE  d.entity_id = $1'
   USING i_entity_id;
END
$func$;
```

Since the input parameter `i_finyear` is type `integer`, there is no danger of SQL injection and you can use plain concatenation to concatenate your schema name like *"tbl2016"*. Else, you'd use `format()` to defend against that. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

You *can* also concatenate (properly quoted) *values*, but it's safer and more efficient to pass the value with the `USING` keyword. See:

- [Replace double quotes with single quotes in Postgres (plpgsql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288759/replace-double-quotes-with-single-quotes-in-postgres-plpgsql/37288895#37288895)

No need to change the `search_path` *additionally*. That would just add an expensive context switch.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it's absolutly working fine, thanks );