# Cannot use variable with EXECUTE command in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have the following plpgsql code. I am trying to use `r.a` as one of the fields to insert into my new table, but it returns the error that `r.a` column does not exist.

```
create or replace function function1() returns void as $$
declare r t%rowtype;
begin
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE f_t(a INT, b INT)');
    for r in select * from t
    LOOP
         EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO f_t(a, b) values (r.a, r.b)');
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
end
```

`t`'s structure is also `(a int,b int)`.

Comment: can you share the structure of the table `t`?

Comment: you cannot to use plpgsql variables in dynamic query - it is executed in different context. Use `USING` clause

Answer (score 3):

Function variables and parameters are ***not visible*** within [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). (Hence the error message *"column r.a does not exist"*.) You have to pass values, best with the `USING` clause. This would *work*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r t%rowtype;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE f_t(a INT, b INT)');
   FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM t
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO f_t(a, b) SELECT $1.*') -- !!
      USING r;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it does not make a whole lot of sense, since you can simply replace it with [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html):

```
CREATE TABLE f_t AS TABLE t;
```

Related:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [How to dynamically use TG_TABLE_NAME in PostgreSQL 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519044/how-to-dynamically-use-tg-table-name-in-postgresql-8-2/7617533#7617533)